# how to write in a same file again and again by stext command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window, file-handling

I have a batch file name *view.bat* when I run

```
start Example.exe /stext Example.text
```

command in `.bat` file , what it does is create a file *`Example.text` but again when I run it, the previous data is lost in existing file how I append new data in existing file.

Comment: What have you tried yourself in solving the issue? Why didn't you want to tell us the real name of the `ChromePass` executable?

Answer (score 0):

The question is most likely about [ChromePass](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html) which is copyright by **Nir Sofer** as supposed by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350210/how-to-write-in-a-same-file-again-and-again-by-stext-command#comment106759916_60350210).

**ChromePass** has no option to append the password data to an existing file instead of creating always a new file with overwriting existing content on file already existing in currently latest version 1.50. I would be best to [contact NirSoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/contact-new.html) and ask for an enhancement for adding an option like `/a` to append the password data to existing file specified on command line.

But there is also a simple solution for `view.bat` by changing the command line

```
start Example.exe /stext Example.text
```

to

```
"ChromePass.exe" /stext "new.tmp"
if exist "new.tmp" (
    if exist "Example.text" (
        copy /B "Example.text" + "new.tmp" "Example.text" >nul
        del "new.tmp"
    ) else ren "new.tmp" "Example.text"
)
```

The command `start` is not necessary and would be counterproductive in this case.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `del /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.